# Combine two list values into one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

is there a way to combine these to list items into one list item ? i am sorry if this is a begginer mistake

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (Feature f in allFeatures)
        {
            if (f.ColumnValues.ContainsKey(layercode)&& f.ColumnValues.ContainsKey(layercode2))
            {
                if (!values.Contains(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()) && !values.Contains(f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString()))
                {
                    values.Add(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString());
                    values.Add(f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString());


                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: @Logan_Jones You meant to combine the strings added in the two values.Add(...) statements?

Comment: i need the add values to be one statement instead of two so i guess one string @avenet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for you, using ";" character as a separator:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (Feature f in allFeatures)
{
    var columnValues = f.ColumnValues;
    var firstLayerCode = columnValues[layercode].ToString();
    var secondLayerCode = columnValues[layercode2].ToString();

    if (columnValues.ContainsKey(layercode) && columnValues.ContainsKey(layercode2))
    {
        if (!values.Contains(firstLayerCode) && !values.Contains(secondLayerCode))
        {
            var combinedValue = firstLayerCode + ";" + secondLayerCode;
            values.Add(combinedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LoganJones Take a look at the code now, think it looks cleaner!! Happy coding!!!

Comment: @LoganJones Please don't take offense, and I'm not going to downvote this, but this isn't a technique you should get in the habit of. If you later need to access these values you will have to perform a string parse. You also have to worry about what happens if firstLayerCode or secondLayerCode already contain a ";" in them. Maybe not a problem in this case, but eventually you will encounter this problem. If you ever do this in a workplace, other experienced programmers will think very poorly of it. The technique is usually limited to CVS files. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use a List of Tuples, a Dictionary, or create a class.  I will not go into depth explaining these as you should be able to easily search and find other questions all about these.  Some of this is from memory so syntax might be a bit off.

**List of Tuples**

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> values = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
//...
if ( !values.Any(v=>v.Item1 == f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()) && !values.Any(v=>v.Item2 == f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString()) )
{
    values.Add( Tuple.Create(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString(),  
                            f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString()) );
}
```

**Dictionary**

```
Dictionary<string,string> values = new Dictionary<string,string> ();
//...
if (!values.ContainsKey(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()) && !values.ContainsValue(f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString()))
{
    values[f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()] = f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString();
}
```

**List of class instances**

```
public class LayerCodePair {
    public string Code1 {get;set;}
    public string Code2 {get;set;}
} // declared outside of method
...

List<LayerCodePair> values = new List<LayerCodePair>();
//...
if (!values.Any(v=> v.Code1 == f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()) && !values.Any(v=>v.Code2 == f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString()))
{
    values.Add(new LayerCodePair{ 
        Code1 = f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString(),
        Code2 = f.ColumnValues[layercode2].ToString()
    });
}
```